# How to save information on Login page?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android. I'm trying to save the information on the Login Screen if I check the CheckBox, but when I turn off the app and turn it on, it clears the information even I had checked the CheckBox (The app runs normally). Am I missing anything or the knowledge that I should know about saving data?

Here is the main activity code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ILoginView {

private var edLoginEmail: EditText? = null
private var edPassword: EditText? = null

private var cbRemember: CheckBox? = null
private var remember: Boolean? = null
private lateinit var loginPreference: SharedPreferences
private lateinit var loginPrefEdit: SharedPreferences.Editor

private lateinit var iLoginPresenter: ILoginPresenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Log.d(MAIN_ACTIVITY_TAG, "#onCreate")
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen)

    edLoginEmail = findViewById(R.id.edEmail)
    edPassword = findViewById(R.id.edPassword)
    iLoginPresenter = LoginPresenter(this)

    cbRemember = findViewById(R.id.cbRemember)
    loginPreference = getSharedPreferences("loginPreference", MODE_PRIVATE)
    loginPrefEdit = loginPreference.edit()

    remember = loginPreference.getBoolean("remember", false)
    if (remember == true) {
        edLoginEmail?.setText(loginPreference.getString("email",""))
        edPassword?.setText(loginPreference.getString("pass",""))
        cbRemember?.isChecked = true
    }

    val bttLogin = findViewById<Button>(R.id.bttLogin)
    bttLogin.setOnClickListener{
        beginLogin()
    }
}

private fun beginLogin() {
    Log.d(MAIN_ACTIVITY_TAG, "#beginLogin")
    val email = edLoginEmail?.text.toString()
    val pass = edPassword?.text.toString()

    if (cbRemember?.isChecked == true) {
        loginPrefEdit.putBoolean("remember", true)
        loginPrefEdit.putString("email", email)
        loginPrefEdit.putString("pass", pass)
    } else {
        loginPrefEdit.clear()
        loginPrefEdit.commit()
    }

    iLoginPresenter.login(email, pass)
}

override fun loginNotification(notification: String) {
    Log.d(MAIN_ACTIVITY_TAG, "#loginNotification")
    if (notification == "Login Successfully") {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        Toast.makeText(this, notification, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, notification, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}}
```

I think the problem is somewhere in here. If you need other parts, just tell me which one, I will update it.

Comment: you need to add `loginPrefEdit.commit()` in both `if` and `else` for checkbox

Comment: Omg, such a stupid mistake from me. Thank you so much